# Java Reflections get url of specific sub-package

Tags: java, reflection

We're building a testing framework and using reflection to scan a package for methods that have been annotated with an annotation we've defined.
Everything is working fairly much as expected,
however,
we've come across something we're finding odd.

Using `ClasspathHelper` from `org.reflections.util` will return a `Set<URL>`,
but it appears to be returning the parent folder's URL instead of the URL of the actual package we want scanned.

For example,
we run `ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.company.project.packageWeWantScanned")`,
we'll get a URL pointing to the folder holding all the classes instead of one pointing to that specific package.
For instance, in the below example file structure,
we get a URL pointing to `classes` instead of `packageWeWantScanned`.

How do we only scan the specific package we want instead of all the classes from the parent folder?

```
classes
└── com
    └── company
        └── project
            ├── packageWeWantScanned
            │   ├── SomeClass.class
            │   ├── SomeOtherClass.class
            │   └── SomeOtherClass.class
            └── packageWeDontWantScanned
                ├── DifferentClass.class
                ├── DifferentOtherClass.class
                └── DifferentSomeOtherClass.class
```

Edit/Update: `Sotirios Delimanolis`'s answer is correct, but just to add additional context for those who happen upon this question, we were originally using:

```
Reflections reflection = new Reflections(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.company.project.packageWeWantScanned"), new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
```

which was causing us to get more than we wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [`ClasspathHelper#forPackage(String, ClassLoader..)`](https://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/org/reflections/util/ClasspathHelper.html#forPackage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader...%29) does

> effectively returns urls from classpath with packages starting with [name]

You probably want to use [`Reflections#getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Class)`](https://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/org/reflections/Reflections.html#getMethodsAnnotatedWith%28java.lang.Class%29).

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.company.project.packageWeWantScanned", new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
System.out.println(reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as advertised. I'm curious though, if we were providing the string as a string "`starting with [name]`", why would the other parent folder be chosen? Shouldn't a prefix that is longer than the parent's path only return the expected path + its children? Why does it get the parent folder instead?

Comment: @BCqrstoO Can you clarify your question? Are you referring to `Reflections`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I'm not being clear. `ClasspathHelper.ForPackage` looks for packages that start with what you provide it, why would it return the parent? EG: `./folder1/` does not start with `./folder1/folder2/` so why does `./folder1` get returned? (Maybe that's not a question for you, as much as it is a question that should actually get directed to whomever implemented it; unless I just don't understand that javadoc.)

Comment: @BCqrstoO I don't like the javadoc wording at all. (I don't think English is the developers' main language.) `ClasspathHelper#forPackage(..)` returns the URL for resources (libraries/jars or file system locations) which contain the package name you provide.

Comment: That clarifies things a lot. Thanks your help... again!